# android OnAnimationEnd, not possible to add image to layout in OnAnimationEnd

Tags: android, animation

`Hi everybody, i have a problem with Android OnAnimationEnd. i have two layouts A and B, A is the parent parent layout and contains B in the middle and an ImageView (imv) at the bottom. Now i need to translate imv from its original position into layout B which is at the middle of layout A such that at the end of the animation imv will belong to layout B and not layout A. to achieve this, in OnAnimationEnd, I removed imv from its parent layout and attempted to then add it to layout B. However at the end the animation imv just vanish as soon as it enters layout B. System.out shows that OnAnimationEnd is called and layout childCount also shows that imv is added to layout B, but imv is never vissible in layout B. below is the code, by the way am not an experienced android developer. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimatorListener {
    ImageView imv;
    RelativeLayout parentL;
    RelativeLayout middleL;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imv.setOnClickListener(new MyClick(this));
        parentL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        middleL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rll);
     }

     private class MyClick implements OnClickListener {
        MainActivity ma;

        public MyClick(MainActivity ma) {
            this.ma = ma;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView imv = (ImageView) v;
            float x = middleL.getX();
            float y = middleL.getY();
            imv.animate().setListener(ma);
            imv.animate().x(x).y(y);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator anim) {
        System.out.println("onAnimationEnd");
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)imv.getParent();
        vg.removeView(imv);
        middleL.addView(imv);
        System.out.println("layout child count = "+middleL.getChildCount());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
        System.out.println("onAnimationStart");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call  invalidate(), it will tell the view it needs to redraw itself

Comment: Thanks Wolverine, but invalidate() is not helping. I will be very grateful if you or someone debug this code for me thank u.

Answer (score 0):

when you define your animation, try using `anim.setFillAfter(true);`